# Noob c#. Trying to verify user input inside a method

Tags: c#, methods, try-catch, static-methods

I´m using an input inside a Loop (While). Also what i want to do is verify the input of the user, inside a method, and if its not a number then it should return back again to ask the input. The problem is that when i try that i have to restart the program. Can someone explain me how to control the code so i can go back in the code? Thanks so much!

```
            Console.WriteLine("Efetue a jogada ->");
            string escolha = Console.ReadLine(); 
            int verificaçaoEscolha = escolhaVerificacao(escolha);

            if(valido == 1){
            Console.WriteLine("Try again");
```

//Method

```
    public static int escolhaVerificacao(string a) {
        int b;
        int valido = 0;

        try {
            int.TryParse(a, out b);
        }
        catch (FormatException) {
            valido = 1;
        }
        return valido;
    }
```

Comment: You dont need a Try/Catch with TryParse - it returns a flag indicating whether **IT** caught an exception for you.

Comment: If you could, try to add a bit more of the code, such as the while loop you mentioned. It looks like this is just a console application and you are trying to verify each character as it is typed. Is there a reason you are validating each character on input rather than verify the entire string when the user is done inputting characters?

Comment: As @Plutonix said, you do not need the try/catch, you can simply check that the return of `TryParse` is true (here is an example of waht Plutonix is talking about): `bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(a, out b);`

Comment: You may not even need the method really.  Typically the point of TryParse is to get the value not just check if it is valid

Answer (score 1):

Int32.TryParse doesn't rise exceptions. It returns true if the input has been converted to an integer

```
public static bool escolhaVerificacao(string a) 
{
    int b;
    return int.TryParse(a, out b);
}
```

and call it with

```
Console.WriteLine("Efetue a jogada ->");
string escolha = Console.ReadLine(); 
bool verificaçaoEscolha = escolhaVerificacao(escolha);
if(!verificaçaoEscolha)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Try again");
}
```

Comment: ...which begs the question why do it in a method since it prevents the calling code from getting the result

Comment: Yeah, I fear the next question will be: how do I get that conversion value from b?